# dir and help not showing all attributes of an object in python?

Tags: python

This is my code so far,

```
import win32com.client as winc

outlook = winc.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
print message.body
```

and `message.body` prints my last e-mail from outlook.

When I `dir(message)` or `help(message)` the attribute `body` does not come. Why?

```
>>> dir(message)
['_ApplyTypes_', '_FlagAsMethod', '_LazyAddAttr_', '_NewEnum', '_Release_', '__AttrToID__', '__LazyMap__', '__call__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__getattr__', '__getitem__', '__init__', '__int__', '__len__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__nonzero__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__str__', '_builtMethods_', '_enum_', '_find_dispatch_type_', '_get_good_object_', '_get_good_single_object_', '_lazydata_', '_make_method_', '_mapCachedItems_', '_oleobj_', '_olerepr_', '_print_details_', '_proc_', '_unicode_to_string_', '_username_', '_wrap_dispatch_']
```

Why is this?

**Update**

*Is there anyway I can get to know all attributes of an object without fail?*

Comment: The short answer is "the win32com module does black magic".

Comment: I am not familiar with the implementation of Outlook messages, but you can get a similar behaviour by overriding the `__getattr__`, which is probably what it does to route requests to the underlying API. In that case, `dir` will not show the method since they are technically not there

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per this page http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir

> Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an
>   interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names
>   more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set
>   of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For
>   example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the
>   argument is a class.

So, we should not rely on `dir` to get to know all about an object. If that class implements `__dir__` method, we ll get only whatever is returned from that method. They might have implemented `__dir__` and abstracted `body` from the `dir` calls.

**Example:**

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myValue = 0
    def myMethod(self):
        pass
    def __dir__(self):
        return []

class TestClass1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myValue = 0
    def myMethod(self):
        pass

print dir(TestClass())
print dir(TestClass1())

print dir(TestClass())
print dir(TestClass1())
```

**Output**

```
[]
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'myMethod', 'myValue']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`__dict__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) method. As it specified in docs, it lists all **writable** attributes, so that might help.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is **NO**, since as [in this case](https://bitbucket.org/amauryfa/pywin32-pypy/src/2a1da51e81526e3c1467682e1b78a76a13763a82/com/win32com/client/__init__.py), object's `__getattr__` method can be overriden. Consider following example:

```
>>> class Const(object):
...     def __init__(self, val):
...         self.value = val
...     def __getattr__(self, a):
...         return self.value
...     def __setattr__(self, a, v)
...         self.__dict__[a] = v
...
>>> c = Const(1)
>>> dir(c)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__',  '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'value']
>>> c.__dict__
{'value': 1}
>>> c.some_strange_attribute_name
1
>>> c.some_strange_attribute_name = 2
>>> c.some_strange_attribute_name
2
```

Comment: Please check my answer. If we override `__dir__`, it will not even show that value.

Comment: @thefourtheye, I already +1ed it :) But in this answer I wanna show some other aspect of the problem