# How to list all Faker methods in python

Tags: python, faker

How do I programatically list all available methods in the Faker generator object?

[Faker docs](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/stable) show how to create the faker generator, and generate data:

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

fake.name()
# 'Lucy Cechtelar'

fake.address()
# '426 Jordy Lodge
#  Cartwrightshire, SC 88120-6700'
```

I would expect the methods `name` and `address` to show up in the listing of the `fake` object, but no luck:

```
dir(fake)
# ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_factories', '_factory_map', '_locales', '_map_provider_method', '_select_factory', '_weights', 'cache_pattern', 'factories', 'generator_attrs', 'items', 'locales', 'random', 'seed', 'seed_instance', 'seed_locale', 'weights']
```

Is there a way to create a list of all methods you can call on the faker generator?

---

**Edit August 3, 2020:**

They finally added this in version 4.0.3, and now it works:

> Implemented **dir** method to Faker proxy for better autocompletion.
> Thanks @douglasfarinelli.

https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564186/dir-and-help-not-showing-all-attributes-of-an-object-in-python?

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
>>> from faker import Faker
>>> F = Faker()
>>> dir(F)
```

I get a long list of methods:

```
[... 'add_provider', 'address', 'am_pm', 'android_platform_token', 'ascii_company_email', 'ascii_email', 'ascii_free_email', 'ascii_safe_email', 'bank_country', 'bban', 'binary', 'boolean', 'bothify', 'bs', 'building_number', 'cache_pattern', 'catch_phrase', 'century', 'chrome', 'city', 'city_prefix', 'city_suffix', 'color', 'color_name', 'company', 'company_email', 'company_suffix', 'coordinate', 'country', 'country_calling_code', 'country_code', 'credit_card_expire', 'credit_card_full', 'credit_card_number', 'credit_card_provider', 'credit_card_security_code', 'cryptocurrency', 'cryptocurrency_code', 'cryptocurrency_name', 'csv', 'currency', 'currency_code', 'currency_name', 'currency_symbol', 'date', 'date_between', 'date_between_dates', 'date_object', 'date_of_birth', 'date_this_century', 'date_this_decade', 'date_this_month', 'date_this_year', 'date_time', 'date_time_ad', 'date_time_between', 'date_time_between_dates', 'date_time_this_century', 'date_time_this_decade', 'date_time_this_month', 'date_time_this_year', 'day_of_month', 'day_of_week', 'dga', 'domain_name', 'domain_word', 'dsv', 'ean', 'ean13', 'ean8', 'ein', 'email', 'factories', 'file_extension', 'file_name', 'file_path', 'firefox', 'first_name', 'first_name_female', 'first_name_male', 'format', 'free_email', 'free_email_domain', 'future_date', 'future_datetime', 'generator_attrs', 'get_formatter', 'get_providers', 'hex_color', 'hexify', 'hostname', 'http_method', 'iban', 'image_url', 'internet_explorer', 'invalid_ssn', 'ios_platform_token', 'ipv4', 'ipv4_network_class', 'ipv4_private', 'ipv4_public', 'ipv6', 'isbn10', 'isbn13', 'iso8601', 'items', 'itin', 'job', 'language_code', 'language_name', 'last_name', 'last_name_female', 'last_name_male', 'latitude', 'latlng', 'lexify', 'license_plate', 'linux_platform_token', 'linux_processor', 'local_latlng', 'locale', 'locales', 'localized_ean', 'localized_ean13', 'localized_ean8', 'location_on_land', 'longitude', 'mac_address', 'mac_platform_token', 'mac_processor', 'md5', 'military_apo', 'military_dpo', 'military_ship', 'military_state', 'mime_type', 'month', 'month_name', 'msisdn', 'name', 'name_female', 'name_male', 'null_boolean', 'numerify', 'opera', 'paragraph', 'paragraphs', 'parse', 'password', 'past_date', 'past_datetime', 'phone_number', 'port_number', 'postalcode', 'postalcode_in_state', 'postalcode_plus4', 'postcode', 'postcode_in_state', 'prefix', 'prefix_female', 'prefix_male', 'profile', 'provider', 'providers', 'psv', 'pybool', 'pydecimal', 'pydict', 'pyfloat', 'pyint', 'pyiterable', 'pylist', 'pyset', 'pystr', 'pystr_format', 'pystruct', 'pytimezone', 'pytuple', 'random', 'random_choices', 'random_digit', 'random_digit_not_null', 'random_digit_not_null_or_empty', 'random_digit_or_empty', 'random_element', 'random_elements', 'random_int', 'random_letter', 'random_letters', 'random_lowercase_letter', 'random_number', 'random_sample', 'random_uppercase_letter', 'randomize_nb_elements', 'rgb_color', 'rgb_css_color', 'safari', 'safe_color_name', 'safe_email', 'safe_hex_color', 'secondary_address', 'seed', 'seed_instance', 'seed_locale', 'sentence', 'sentences', 'set_formatter', 'sha1', 'sha256', 'simple_profile', 'slug', 'ssn', 'state', 'state_abbr', 'street_address', 'street_name', 'street_suffix', 'suffix', 'suffix_female', 'suffix_male', 'tar', 'text', 'texts', 'time', 'time_delta', 'time_object', 'time_series', 'timezone', 'tld', 'tsv', 'unix_device', 'unix_partition', 'unix_time', 'upc_a', 'upc_e', 'uri', 'uri_extension', 'uri_page', 'uri_path', 'url', 'user_agent', 'user_name', 'uuid4', 'weights', 'windows_platform_token', 'word', 'words', 'year', 'zip', 'zipcode', 'zipcode_in_state', 'zipcode_plus4']
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Wright, they added it in v4.0.3 and it works now. Previous versions didn't have this functionality.